# Withdrawal from Bitcoin bonus

Tags: wallet, mining-pools

Bitcoin bonus keeps emailing me over and over sayn I gt 30000 dollars to be withdraw but I gotta pay 64 dollars to get my funds why they can't take the 64 dollars out the money and then send it it's gettn aggravating and irritating if it's not real I wish they would stop

Comment: It is a scam 99,9%